# Skyrim - My Follower Is Missing/Lost

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard, skyrim-hearthfire, skyrim-dragonborn

So today I was completing a few quests and after I cleared a dungeon out i wanted to trade with my follower but he wasnt there!I checked the WHOLE dungeon and no sign of him.I also dont have any quest which makes you have another follower.Also if I try to recruit another follower it just says I already have one.

Also im on PC and my follower was called Stenvar.I have tried the prid 000B998C moveto player command and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

- They're dead. Sorry. If you want your stuff, you'll want to find where they died. If they where with you up to just recently, backtracking shouldn't be too difficult.
- They bugged out. This one's pretty easy to resolve: enter a new area or fast travel somewhere. They'll be right behind you.
- They went home. Return to where you picked them up originally: in the case of Lydia, that means Breezehome (if you've purchased it) or Dragonsreach in Whiterun.
- For PC, you can enter console commands (get to the console by pressing the tilde key, which is ` or ~ on your keyboard, usually under the Esc key and to the left of the 1 key):

```
prid <RefID>
moveto player
```

Lydia's RefID is `a2c94` and Iona is `a2c93`
 Google your follower, if it's not either of them i'm sure it's online.

Comment: One question,i try to enter the console command for pc prid 000B998C moveto player (for stenvar) and it doesnt work for me..

Comment: what does it say?

Comment: It says Missing parameter ObjectReferenceID and it also says Compiled Script Not Saved!.Also it says Expected end of line.

Comment: can you post a picture on imgur please?